# How to change function return value with decorators in python?

Tags: python, decorator

I have this function and a decorator @decorator(integer)

```
def spam():
    return "ABCD EFG"

def decorator(number):
    def inside(function):
        *do something*
        return *somthing of type string*
    return inside
```

I want to make the decorator return FUNCTION, accepts integer and replaces every letter with the letter comming in `number` places afterwards. For example

```
@decorator(3)
def spam():
    return "ABCD EFG"
```

and

```
>>> print(spam())
"DEFG HIJ"
```

- How do i make the decorator return a function and not a string  ?

Comment: Should the decorator just add a random thing at the end? Always add `HIJ`? Or what?

Comment: it replaces every letter with the letter comming in `number` places. e -> h , f -> i ,g ->j

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in order to define a decorator:

```
def decorator(number):
    def inner(f):
        def decorator_f(*args, **kwargs):
            result = f(*args, **kwargs)
            #make some manipulation on result
            return result
        return decorator_f
    return inner
```

Then you can use it like:

```
@decorator(3)
def spam():
    return "ABCD EFG"
```

Comment: Exactly what i was trying to do! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use normal methods:

```
def spam(number):
    s = "ABCD EFG"
    return ''.join(chr(ord(x)+number) if x.isalpha() else x for x in s)
```

If you have to use decorators, implement them as @Udy has shown and the line that I have provided above is how you can return the shifted values.

Comment: Because my task is to use decorators.